# Why is this hashmap acting so weird?: Accessing hashmap through methods from different classes

Tags: java, hashmap

Here's the troubled method that we are looking at acting similar to a library. It's purpose is to have a hashmap available and easily editable by all classes:

```
package main;
import java.util.*;

public class Game_Data_Handler {
HashMap<String, Integer> Data_Int = new HashMap<String, Integer>(); 
    public void Setup() {
        Data_Int.put("test", 1);
    }

    public void SetInt(String Value_To_Change, int SetVal) {
        Data_Int.put(Value_To_Change, SetVal);
    }
    public int RecallInt(String RecallVal) {
        return Data_Int.get(RecallVal);
    }
}
```

---

Let's try some code here:

```
public class Main_Class {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game_Data_Handler GDH = new Game_Data_Handler();
        GDH.Setup();
        System.out.println(GDH.RecallInt("test"));
    }
}
```

That would output "1" in the console.

---

Let's try this now:

```
public class Main_Class {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game_Data_Handler GDH = new Game_Data_Handler();
        GDH.Setup();
            Sub_Class SC = new Sub_Class();
            SC.Print();
    }
}

public class Sub_Class {

        public static void Print() {
            Game_Data_Handler GDH = new Game_Data_Handler();
            System.out.println(GDH.RecallInt("test"));
        }
    }
```

Then I would get a `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

---

**Why is this happening? How can I fix this?**

If forgot I had two different instances. But without creating the instances, there were problems with static/non-static methods. What would be a better solution so I could call it without making new instances from a static method?

Comment: There's nothing "weird" about this behavior. You've got two different map instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're putting nothing in your `HashMap<String, Integer> Data_Int` for the `GDH`instance in your `Print()`method.

Hence `Data_Int.get(RecallVal);` will return `null` and throw the NPE when trying to get the `int` value of the `Integer` by calling `.intValue()` ([unboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html))

Actually, `RecallInt` could be written like this (for a better comprehension of the problem) :

```
public int RecallInt(String RecallVal) {
     Integer i = Data_Int.get(RecallVal);
     return i.intValue();
}
```

Every time you will call this method with a key that your map doesn't have, your program will throw a NPE.

Comment: Ohh since I created two separate instances. How do I fix this? I did this because I was having problems with static/non-static methods.

Comment: @AnnonomusPerson For each instance you have to call setup() method otherwise make that method as static and the map too ,which shares across all instances.

Comment: @AnnonomusPerson What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to call `Setup()` on the `GDH` variable you create here:

```
public static void Print() {
            Game_Data_Handler GDH = new Game_Data_Handler();
            System.out.println(GDH.RecallInt("test"));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Sub_Class SC = new Sub_Class();
  SC.Print();
```

Now print method calling.

```
 public static void Print() {
            Game_Data_Handler GDH = new Game_Data_Handler();
            System.out.println(GDH.RecallInt("test"));
        }
```

Now recall int

```
public int RecallInt(String RecallVal) {
        return Data_Int.get(RecallVal);
    }
```

Since there is no elements in your map

```
Data_Int.get(RecallVal)
```

it is null. and trying to get  the int value from that.

Resolution :

call `setUp()`  method before using it.

As a side note please follow [`java naming conventions.`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html), variable name starts with small case letter.

Answer (score 0):

In the second example you never call `Setup()` in `print()` method.

Causing `GDH.RecallInt("test")` return null, and thus throwing NPE.